# Ubuntu does not detect second nVidia GPU

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I have 2 GPUs installed on my system: a GTX660 and a 8800GTS. Both are detected and run perfectly under Windows 8, and Ubuntu 12.04 32bits.

I've now installed Ubuntu 12.04 64bits on the same system, with the latest drivers from nVidia (304.64 in 64bits). In console mode (CTR + ALT + F1), I can detect and use both cards (through, e.g., a CUDA application).

In X-mode (I use the standard lightdm server), the same application only detects the GTX660. Running lspci from an X terminal shows both GPUs (the GTX660 is referred to as a "VGA compatible controller" while the 8800GTS is clearly referenced in plain).

It seems to me to be related to the X-server, more than anything.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It may be a permission issue. What happens if you run your application with `sudo` in X? What's the output of `ls -l /dev/nvidia*`?

Comment: it may be a conflict with the [nouveau driver](https://www.benjaminwiedmann.net/fix-nouveau-driver-issues-on-ubuntu-12-04-install-nvidia-drivers.html) latched onto one of the GPUs.

Comment: the change with nomodeset is indicative of a nouveau issue.  By preventing any modesets early in the boot process, the nvidia driver can take control of the GPU away from the nouveau driver.  For more description, read [section 8.1](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/304.64/README/commonproblems.html) of the NVIDIA Driver readme.

Comment: If you managed to solve it, please turn that into an answer and accept it. Then it's clear to all of us you've solved your problem and what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved - but I'm not 100% sure why.

In the meantime, I've been modifying my grub config (see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)) by adding the `nomodeset` attribute in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_DEFAULT` line, as I couldn't access a console.

Since then, the problem seemed to be solved, i.e., I can now see my two GPUs even under X.

The `ls -l /dev/nvidia*` is returning both devices and the controller.

Thanks anyway for your speedy help!